# List containers in the same docker-compose

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerpy

I am working on an application that takes advantage of `docker-compose`. One of the containers is a watchdog component, that runs a small python script periodically to get the states of the sibling containers, and takes action if one of the containers stopped.

To this point I used a list of all container names that should be watched, but now I was wondering it I could just watch all containers created by the same `docker-compose` command.

Previously, the code looked something like this:

```
watched_containers = ["component-a", "component-b"]
def inspect_containers():
    containers = {
        (container["Names"][0].lstrip("/"), container)
        for container in docker.Client().containers(all=True)
    }

    for container_name in watched_containers:
        if containers.get(container_name, {}).get("State") != "running":
            alert_container_stopped(container_name)
```

I found that `dockerpy` does not know about `docker-compose`, so I created a function that filters the containers based on docker-compose project name label (`com.docker.compose.project`), but now I have a hardcoded project name instead of container names. Is there a way to get the current project name, or are there other ways to obtain the list of containers in the same compose?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a quick idea off the top of my head.

As you're using the Docker client library in the watchdog container, I'm assuming that you have access to the host's Docker API from within the watchdog container. As each container's hostname is the container ID by default, you can use this to have the watchdog container look up its own labels from the Docker API.

Below is an example using the Docker CLI; the Python SDK should work exactly the same way:

```
$ COMPOSE_PROJECT=$(docker inspect -f '{{ (index .Config.Labels "com.docker.compose.project") }}' $HOSTNAME)
```

Then use the project name to get the remaining containers:

```
$ docker ps -aq -f label=com.docker.compose.project=$COMPOSE_PROJECT
```

Comment: On my system the hostname variable in the container is not set to the containerid, but I have found an other way of obtaining that (using cgroup).

Answer (score 2):

The new (June 2021) [docker compose V2](https://docs.docker.com/compose/cli-command/) could simplify this query with:
[`docker compose ls`](https://github.com/docker/compose-cli/blob/main/cmd/compose/list.go)

> List running compose projects

Since compose is part of Docker commands, you can call it from your python program.